# I get 3% failure rate when my users click on branch.io link

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io, deeplink

When I look at our logs I can see that some of my users are coming from a branch click because the query string contains a _branch_match_id. Say:

https://example.com/?_branch_match_id=123456789

For those cases I call

branch.init(key, {branch_match_id=_branch_match_id}, callback)

but the response comes back with no usable data as if the user did not click on my branch.io link.

I get this type of error on around 3% of cases.

Has anyone noticed a behavior like this on your system?

What strategies did you follow to circumvent this issue?

Did you try other systems to replace branch.io? which ones?

Comment: Is this failure is replicable only with specific browsers or apps? Or the failure happens on different browsers/apps at different times?

Comment: I'm seeing this in chrome, edge, firefox, safari, etc... We use branch.io in one of our apps only.

Comment: The issue is not easy to replicate but we have logs that show it happening for our users. The only way to replicate it in a semi-reliable way (albeit artificial in nature) has been to copy/paste two of our links to the chrome address bar and go back and forth between those two links. That helped us to narrow down this issue to what it seems to be a problem in branch.io side. However, they were not able to give me a solution for this. I'm wondering if this is happening to other companies using branch.io too.